# Torque and a Stretched Rubber Band Wrapped Around an Axle

Tags: torque

I have to define torque as it relates to my rubber band powered car that I made for my physics class, but the way I chose to build my car does not have any obvious torque-ish qualities as it relates to the rubber band. I simply cut the rubber band in half and wound it counter-clockwise around the axle of the car. I am hoping to talk about torque as it relates to my car, but if not I'll just compare and contrast my car to my friend's car (he used a propeller).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your rubber band does cause a torque on the axle. The rubber band exerts a tension force, due to it being stretched, tangent to the outer surface of the axle due to static friction between the rubber band and the surface of the axle. The torque is the product of the tension force times the radius of the axle

Hope this helps